# php header and footer files not showing up

Tags: php

I have created a top bar and a bottom bar for my website's index. I have isolated both of them in two files, the header.php, which controls the top bar and the footer.php, which controls the bottom bar.

```
<? php include "footer.php";?> <? php include "header.php";?>
```

while including the tags for both header and footer files and running the index.php file in chrome doesnot show the layout instead show the code.

Comment: is this your actual syntax? `<? php` with those spaces in there? That's what I pulled from editing your question and was the code that was included in the question.

Comment: Try `<?php` instead of `<? php`

Comment: ...not "try" but "do". and if that still doesn't work, then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Plus, your question is rather short on detail such how you're accessing this file. Sure hoping you'll be paying attention to comments here and getting in on this. Many just completely ignore those and wastes everyone's valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation in my opinion is that you run the index.php file directly in the browser. Do you use a web server as xampp?